# QApplication::exec() refuses to return (in console program)

Tags: c++, qt

I have a Qt C++ program that, although it isn't actually using a GUI (with the exception of a few message box popups) makes use of the `QApplication::exec()`
method (necessary so the event loop is run and can service the whole signal/slot business). I'm also calling `QApplication::setQuitOnLastWindowClosed( false )` because otherwise the program would end immediately when the user dismisses one of the message box popups. I don't think this should have any influence on the behavior I'm observing, but I'm mentioning it anyway, just in case.

At some point, of course, the program should end, and I have added a call to `QApplication::exit()` to cause Qt to fall out of its event loop and thus return from the `QApplication::exec()` call. According to the [Qt documention on the QApplication::exec() method](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#exec), this is precisely what *should* happen.

> **int QApplication::exec()**
>
> Enters the main event loop and waits until exit() is called, then
>   returns the value that was set to exit() (which is 0 if exit() is
>   called via quit()).

However, in my program it's just not happening. I've traced the program flow in a debugger and I know for sure that `QApplication::exit()` is called, but still `QApplication::exec()` doesn't seem to want to return. :(

I'm using Qt 5.4.1 with MinGW 3.11 (the GCC compiler identifies itself as version 4.9.1). My computer is running Windows 7 Enterprise (64 bit), Service Pack 1. Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

EDIT: Kuba Ober mentioned in his comment that `QApplication::exec()` is probably not returning because my code is blocking somewhere. I'd like to post this screenshot of the main thread's call stack to prove that the main thread is stuck deep inside the guts of Qt at this point and that my own code is not in fact in control.

[image: Main thread call stack]

**SOLUTION:** Ok, Rudolfs Bundulis' answer led me to the root of the problem. I had a little message box in my program that pops up and asks the user to perform a certain action (in this case, to switch on an external device that communicates with my program). For the program flow to continue, it is not necessary to dismiss this popup; it is sufficient to simply turn on the external device, and so I forgot to dismiss the message box and just left it alone. Later, when `QApplication::exit()` is called, Qt seems to destroy the message box (or at least make it invisible) so it can no longer be dismissed, and as Rudolfs Bundulis has pointed out, an open message box is enough to keep `QApplication::exec()` from returning.

Comment: Minimal reproducible code example would be nice.

Comment: The event loop can't exit when your code is in control. You're blocking somewhere. It's not magic: your code should be called from the event loop and you should always promptly return to it. Also: the event loop is not necessary to handle direct signal/slot connections.

Comment: @KubaOber I've posted a screenshot of my main thread's call stack to show that this cannot be the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mechanism you described should work. Here is a small snippet with two ways of terminating a `QApplication` just the way you inteded - either via a direct the `QApplication::quit()` slot or the `QApplication::exit()` call. Both seem to work.

QApplicationTerminator.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QApplication>

class QApplicationTerminator : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public slots:
    void quit()
    {
        qDebug() << "terminating QApplication\n";
        QApplication::exit(0);
    }
};
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "qapplicationterminator.h"

#include <QApplication>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QThread>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication application(argc, argv);
    QApplicationTerminator terminator;
    QTimer::singleShot(3000, &application, SLOT(quit()));
    //QTimer::singleShot(3000, &terminator, SLOT(quit()));
    application.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(false);
    auto result = application.exec();
    qDebug() << "event loop exited\n";
    return result;
}
```

I'll have to agree with @KubaOber that most likely you are either blocking somewhere.

Since you mentioned dialogs - dialogs run their own event loop, if any of the event loops of your dialogs are still running (this however should not happen if they are properly used) the main event loop simply does not get back in control and cannot exit.

Comment: You know what, that's exactly what the reason was! :-) There's a message box in my program that pops up to prompt the user to perform a certain action. It is not necessary to actually click the message box, and so I forgot to dismiss it. If I do dismiss it before performing the action, this whole problem goes away.

Still, it's notable that on calling QApplication::exit(), the message box disappears and hence can no longer be dismissed but apparently still prevents QApplication::exec() from returning, which IMO is something that should be fixed in the Qt framework.

Comment: @antred weird, I wanted to make an example that shows this behavior, but even launching a `QFileDialog` and then calling `QApplication::exit()` from the `directoryEntered` slot which should be emitted in the dialogs event loop still causes the application to exit. So it means that the event loop of the dialog properly propagates events or does something else since `QFileDialog::exec` returns and so does `QApplication::exit()`. What did you mean by "the message box disappears" ?

Comment: I mean that it literally just vanishes in thin air. The moment the call to QApplication::exit() is run, the message box simply is not there anymore. Qt seems to close it or at least make it invisible. :(

By the way, I'm using the following code to bring up the message box in question: QMessageBox::information( nullptr, tr( "Start" ), messageToShow );